# Nativescript: Render tapable and linked hashtags # and @mentions from a comment

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm developing an app with NativeScript+Angular where users can comment posts and mention users using the @ symbol, and hashtags using #.

For example, a comment has the following text:

```
Hello @JohnDoe did you enjoy the conference of #NativeScript ?
```

What I need is to render @JohnDoe and #Nativescript as a blue and tapable word, that would be nsRouterLinked to an user profile or a hashtag.

I've found FormattedString (https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/formatted-string) but it seems that Spans are not tapable.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671) for supporting tap event on FormattedString. The Github issue also includes a [sample project](https://github.com/tsonevn/clickableSpanIOSAndroid) on Github that demonstrates handling this natively.

There is also [HtmlView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/htmlview#htmlview) which supports embedding anchor tags, upon click it can automatically handle http & deep links.